# Migrating from Apache Ignite to GridGain Community Edition

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Currently, We are using Apache Ignite version 2.8.1. We want to migrate to GridGain Community Edition: 8.7.32

Wanted to know GridGain version: 8.7.32 is compatible with which Apache Ignite Version.

Also, we are using the below dependencies in Ignite

- ignite-core
- ignite-spring
- ignite-visor-console

What're the equivalent dependencies in GridGain?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Maven `pom.xml` skeleton as a reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ...

    <properties>
        <gridgain.version>8.7.32</gridgain.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>GridGain External Repository</id>
            <url>http://www.gridgainsystems.com/nexus/content/repositories/external</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- GG CE / Apache Ignite -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
            <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-visor-console</artifactId>
            <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

With regards of versions, 8.7.32 should be on par with Apache Ignite 2.9.1 feature-wise.

Comment: any reference to doc for version compatibility? like if we want for Ignite 2.8.1

Comment: It's recommended to use the latest stable version, which is `8.7.32` currently. There's no explicit compatibility with Apache Ignite versions.